# Nested list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, syntax, list-comprehension

I tried to use the value of an outer list comprehension in an inner one:

```
[ x for x in range(y) for y in range(3) ]
```

But unfortunately this raises a `NameError` because the name `y` is unknown (although the outer list comprehension specifies it).

Is this a limitation of Python (2.7.3 and 3.2.3 tried) or is there a good reason why this cannot work?

Are there plans to get rid of the limitation?

Are there workarounds (some different syntax maybe I didn't figure out) to achieve what I want?

Comment: A good way to remember the order is to think about how you would do this without list comprehension (someone recently mentioned this, and it stuck)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are talking about list *comprehensions*, not generator expressions.

You need to swap your for loops:

```
[ x for y in range(3) for x in range(y) ]
```

You need to read these as if they were nested in a regular loop:

```
for y in range(3):
    for x in range(y):
        x
```

List comprehensions with multiple loops follow the same ordering. See the [list comprehension documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

> When a list comprehension is supplied, it consists of a single expression followed by at least one `for` clause and zero or more `for` or `if` clauses. In this case, the elements of the new list are those that would be produced by considering each of the `for` or `if` clauses a block, nesting from left to right, and evaluating the expression to produce a list element each time the innermost block is reached.

The same thing goes for generator expressions, of course, but these use `()` parenthesis instead of square brackets and are not immediately materialized:

```
>>> (x for y in range(3) for x in range(y))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x100b50410>
>>> [x for y in range(3) for x in range(y)]
[0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: +1 thanks Martijn, I never understood the order until now. (Might have something to do with that "not being obvious unless you're Dutch" thing.)

Comment: I have to keep in mind that iteratively it would be `for A: for B: C` while in comprehensions it is not (as I expected) `C for B for A` but `C for A for B`.  That's curious, I guess even if you're Dutch ;-)

Comment: @Alfe: I note that the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) was written by Barry Warsaw, Bass Player Extraordinaire and All-Round American, not Guido. :-P Although all the original work was done by Greg Ewing. That's a New Zealander. Perhaps that's why.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
[x for y in range(3) for x in range(y)]
```

Because that produces an output... This produces:

```
[0, 0, 1]
```

Which may or may not be what you wanted....

Comment: It's what I want, yes.  My usecase is a bit more complicated, of course:

Comment: return [ value
            for target in targetSet
            for topic, value in self.db[target].keys()
            if topic == chosenTopic ]

Comment: @Levon, sometimes answers get posted at the same time. Once I hit submit, I found out others beat me to it. I then decided to add the output of running this, as the others didn't include that (yet - I haven't checked).

Comment: actually it just became this: `list(set(value for target in targetSet for topic, values in self.db[target].iteritems() if topic == chosenTopic for value in values if (topic, value) not in trail))`.  I wonder if anyone could guess what I'm doing now ;-)

Comment: And another thing: `set([ topic
            for target in targetSet
            for topic, values in self.db[target].iteritems()
            if set((topic, value) for value in values) - trail ])`.  But now I'm drifting off-topic, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

just nest another gen.

```
[ x for x in [range(y) for y in range(3) ]]
```

gives me:

```
[[], [0], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: But list of lists isn't what I need.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Alfe well your question was not very clear. go with martijns answer then. :)