# Duplicating list items variable number of times with list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I am basically trying to get my head around using a list comprehension with this basic bit of code. Im trying to duplicate a list item by the value of the list item:

```
y = [1, 2, 0, 1]
x = []
for i in y:
    for j in range(i):
        x.append(i)
# Desired output
>>> [1, 2, 2, 1]

x = [i for _ in range(i) for i in y]
# Wrong output
>>> [1, 2, 0, 1]

# Right output
x = [j for j in y for _ in range(j)]
>>> [1, 2, 2, 1]
```

I just cant seem to get my head around why I get the wrong output for the second example. Could someone explain what is wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Your first comprehension `[i for _ in range(i) for i in y]` will give an error on execution(Namely, `name 'i' is not defined`). In nested list comprehensions, loops go from outside in.

Comment: @Rahul It wouldn't raise that error because the `for` loop in the previous lines will leak the value of `i`.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17657966/4014959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple `for` loops inside a list comprehension, the loops are processed in the same order as they would be using "traditional" `for` loops. Your list comp that gives the correct output has the loops in the same order as your code at the start using `.append` with traditional `for` loops.

As Rahul mentions in the comments, in isolation,

```
x = [i for _ in range(i) for i in y]
```

would give a

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

It doesn't in this case because `i` was defined by the earlier code.

---

In contrast, look at what happens with a nested list comp:

```
y = [1, 2, 0, 1]
x = [[j for j in range(i)] for i in y]
print(x)
```

**output**

```
[[0], [0, 1], [], [0]]
```

Here, the outermost loop is in the outer comprehension and the inner loop is in the inner comprehension. So for each iteration of the `for i in y` we create a new list comp, and in that list comp we loop over `range(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

The right comprehension is:

```
x = [i for i in y for j in range(i)]
```

This give the result you want
item for item in list range(item) times
inspired by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264684/flatten-list-of-lists)

```
flattened = [val for sublist in list_of_lists for val in sublist]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = [j for j in y for i in range(j)]
```

Comment: This code is a bit confusing because it re-uses `y`. Also, it's always better on SO to add some explanation to your code. Code-only answers with no explanation are of limited usefulness.